# DB QUERY IN ORACLE

Tags: duplicates, void

```
SELECT 
    BILLS.* 
FROM 
    BATELCO_BILLS_S BILLS 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
         BTL_BILL_I_NUMBER, 
         MAX(R_MODIFY_DATE) AS MAXDATETIME 
    FROM 
        BATELCO_BILLS_S  
    GROUP BY 
         BTL_BILL_I_NUMBER
) GROUPEDBILLS
    ON BILLS.BTL_BILL_I_NUMBER = GROUPEDBILLS.BTL_BILL_I_NUMBER AND
       BILLS.R_MODIFY_DATE = GROUPEDBILLS.MAXDATETIME 
WHERE 
    (BILLS.BTL_BILL_I_CPR = :B3 OR BILLS.BTL_BILL_C_CPR = :B3) AND
    (TO_DATE(BTL_BILL_I_DATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE(:B2, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND
     TO_DATE(:B1, 'dd/mm/yyyy') OR
     TO_DATE(BTL_BILL_C_DATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE(:B2, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND
     TO_DATE(:B1, 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
```

Please help to get optimize the query by avoiding the join so that GROUP BY is required.

AVOID DUPLICATE BTL_BILL_I_NUMBER AND FETCH THE RESULTS.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid join? What you've tried? What is the PRACTICAL problem you want to solve?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rewrite this using an analytic function, such as `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BTL_BILL_I_NUMBER
                           ORDER BY R_MODIFY_DATE DESC) rn
    FROM BATELCO_BILLS_S 
    WHERE 
        (BTL_BILL_I_CPR = :B3 OR BTL_BILL_C_CPR = :B3) AND
        (TO_DATE(BTL_BILL_I_DATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE(:B2, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND
         TO_DATE(:B1, 'dd/mm/yyyy') OR
         TO_DATE(BTL_BILL_C_DATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE(:B2, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND
         TO_DATE(:B1, 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

I'm not an expert in Oracle's syntax, and the `SELECT *` calls I have above may not work.  If not, then you can (and rightfully should) list out the columns you want to actually select.

Comment: Thanks for the query.

Comment: @SreejithA Did this answer help you?

Comment: Yes Sir SELECT * FROM ( SELECT A_WEBC_URL AS FILE_LOCATION FROM BATELCO_BILLS_S WHERE BTL_BILL_I_NUMBER = :B2 AND BTL_BILL_I_ACC_NUMBER = '0' || :B1 
UNION SELECT A_WEBC_URL AS FILE_LOCATION FROM BATELCO_BILLS_S WHERE BTL_BILL_I_NUMBER = :B2 AND (BTL_BILL_I_PROFILE_ID = :B1 OR BTL_BILL_I_PHONE_NUMBER = :B3 ) 
UNION SELECT A_WEBC_URL AS SS FROM BATELCO_BILLS_S BILLS WHERE BILLS.BTL_BILL_I_PROFILE_ID = :B1 OR BTL_BILL_I_ACC_NUMBER = '0' || :B1 AND BILLS.BTL_BILL_I_NUMBER = :B2 ) WHERE ROWNUM = 1 Can you please help to sort out the below query

Comment: Done with checking the green tick

Answer (score 0):

I am not an oracle expert but here is what I would have done:

- Avoid using * in the selected columns, instead mention each and every column you need;
- No need of join. You are working on the same table (see below example);
- Add index to the column used in where clause

---

```
SELECT BILLS.btl_bill_i_number, Max(r_modify_date) AS MAXDATETIME 
FROM   batelco_bills_s BILLS 
GROUP  BY btl_bill_i_number        
WHERE  ( BILLS.btl_bill_i_cpr = :B3 
OR BILLS.btl_bill_c_cpr = :B3 ) 
AND ( To_date(btl_bill_i_date) BETWEEN To_date(:B2, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND To_date(:B1, 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
OR To_date(btl_bill_c_date) BETWEEN To_date(:B2, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND 
To_date(:B1, 'dd/mm/yyyy') )
```

Hope this helps :)